# Node.js package self-reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, require

Can package `require` itself and its subsystems?

For instance there is module:
`src/deep/path/to/module.js`
which need to require
`src/another/module.js`

Instead of:

```
require('./../../../another/module.js');
```

Can one just:

```
require('<self>/another/module.js');
```

?

For instance this might be useful in testing: test unit can reference its test object without long up-and-down-style path.

I have two considerations (but they do not satisfies this issue completely):

1. If package is already in `node_modules` folder it can reference to itself by its 
   canonical name (that in its `package.json`).
2. Package can create symlink to itself in its own `node_modules` folder (sic!). Haven't try it yet, possible will lead to infinite loop in some resolving cases.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

Split it to different sub-projects, put each one into different folders. As an example:

```
  sub.project.1/  
  sub.project.2/
```

in sub.project.1/

```
  # cd ../sub.project.1
  npm link

  # cd ../sub.project.2
  npm link sub.project.1
```

Then in sub.project.2 you can do it simply:

var something = require("sub.project.1")

This can remove the '../../...' relative path.

*Note:* it can be done in same folder/project, by doing this,
in the sub folders, the project *self* can be easily referred.
For example when both `sub.project.1` and `sub.project.2` replaced by `my.project`. And of course, all the names should be the `name` in `package.json` initialized by npm.

## Solution 2

Create a link in the folder `node_modules/`

```
  # cd node_modules
  ln  -s ..  myProjectRootDir
  #
  # where: .. : means parent directory in linux shell
  # '#' means comments in linux shell
  #
```

Then it can be used under same level directory trees:

```
  var something = require("myProjectRootDir/path/to/js/file")
```

Thus the "../../..." can change to path read more easily.
And if `myProjectRootDir` happens to be the project name and
package name in `package.json`, it's ok.

## Solution 3

There are npm packages: `require-self`, `install-self`,
they do the similar things.

## Solution 4

Write a new `.js` file where it's easy to `require`,
then put all the annoying relative references into it.

For example write it at `node_modules/mymods.js`

```
  // mymod.js
  module.exports.mod_one = require("../path/to/mod/one.js"); 
  //...
```

Then `require('mymod')` can gives all the other modules.
This is not the best solution, all references of requiring 
need to be doing by hand.  But it's a single file, so it's
manageable, and centralize the references for future deployments.

One of the cons of this solution is, if you put it in 
`node_modules/` folder and this folder is ignored in git repository, you need to take care when pushing or branching the git repo.

When deleting the node_modules folder, the file can also be deleted by accidents.

## There could be more solutions I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can shorten it a little bit. You don't need the leading `./` in this case

```
require("../../../another/module.js");
```

And a little further by removing the trailing `.js`

```
require("../../../another/module");
```

---

Another answer is suggesting the use of `process.cwd()` but be very careful with this. Your `require` calls will only work if the app is initialized from the same directory.

---

From the sounds of it though, 4 directories is already pretty deep. You might want to considering fragmenting your large project into smaller, single-purpose modules. We would need more information on the project to know if that was the right decision though.

Answer (score 0):

I often use `process.cwd()` to make things like this a little more manageable. This returns where the node application is actually running from and lets you create the path in a little cleaner fashion.

Something maybe like `var x = require(process.cwd() + '/lib/module')`

Without seeing exactly what you're trying to do; I'm not sure if this will be helpful, but you can do things like `var connect = require('express/connect')` as well. Basically you can pass an installed local module, and then create paths off of it as well.

Comment: why not use `path.join()` and `__dirname` seems safer than `process.cwd()` ?